# Confirmation for deleting draft documentation Example

Tags: feature-request, documentation, draft

Currently, while editing a Topic, one can click on "Delete" button for an added draft Example and it is nuked without any confirmation or chance to undo, potentially ruining a lot of work due to a single misclick.

For comparison, when editing an existing Example, clicking that button requires confirmation.

**Feature request:** Require confirmation when deleting draft Examples. May be limited to Examples with non-empty body.

Comment: Or better yet, an [undo button](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/71960/deletion-confirm-or-undo-which-is-the-better-option-and-why).

Comment: @DanielM. I think it's not so obvious how an undo/rollback would work here. Suppose there's an edit that migrates an example from one topic to another and then deletes the original topic. How do you roll that back? Do you have to find the deleted topic and do it from there? Or if you do it from the destination topic, does the rollback recreate the deleted topic? If you have a proposal, you could post it on meta; I'd be curious to see what folks have in mind for that.

Comment: @Frank I think this is referring to accidentally clicking the trash can icon on an *example*. Then it's pretty clear how it would work- the example would simply pop back up as if the icon was never clicked. Migrating an example already requires confirmation.

Comment: @DanielM. Where would you display the "undo" UI though?

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying. The UI could just be -- it put you into the UI for a proposal, in which you can "discard" changes. I thought you meant some broader undo functionality.

Answer (score 2):

A UI for undoing deleting an example could simply look something like this:

[image: Example]

Of course, the formatting would be a bit different than this (the mockup is the result of about 30 seconds with "Inspect Element") but the basic idea would be the same.